# Trying to build a ShieldUI chart from an Ajax data source

Tags: ajax, shieldui

I am trying to include a ShieldUI chart and grid in an existing site that uses a View/Viewmodel setup. I have the underlying js functions pulling in the data from an API using an Ajax call and defining the ShieldUI controls but I have been unable to display the controls in the html pages.

I have tried to put the JavaScript code in the HTML pages but it is not able to access the API data. In any case, I would prefer to keep the JavaScript code in the HTML pages to a minimum.

Is it even possible to do this? Or is ShieldUI the wrong product?

Answer (score -1):

It is possible. I have done it, having worked it out for myself. Although I paid for the premium Shield UI product, with support, Shield UI provided no support, documentation or examples to assist.

Even though Shield UI is less expensive, it is not the right product if you don't know exactly what you are doing. A more expensive product might be better. If you do know what you are doing, use a free product.